# Training RNN with LSTM Nodes

Tags: python, scikit-learn, keras, keras-layer

Here is my code to train an RNN with LSTM nodes:

```
# LSTM RNN with dropout for sequence classification
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pickle, numpy, pandas as pd

###################################### CONSTANTS #############################################

SEED = 7                        # Fixes random seed for reproducibility.
URL = 'ibcData.tsv'             # Specified dataset to gather data from.
SEPERATOR = '\t'                # Seperator the dataset uses to divide data.
RANDOM_STATE = 1                # Pseudo-random number generator state used for random sampling.
TOP_WORDS = 5000                # Most used words in the dataset.
MAX_REVIEW_LENGTH = 500         # Length of each sentence being sent in (necessary).
EMBEDDING_VECTOR_LENGTH = 32    # The specific Embedded later will have 32-length vectors to
                                # represent each word.
BATCH_SIZE = 64                 # Takes 64 sentences at a time and continually retrains RNN.
NUMBER_OF_EPOCHS = 3            # Fits RNN to more accurately guess the data's political bias.
DROPOUT = 0.2                   # Helps slow down overfitting of data (slower convergence rate)
RECURRENT_DROPOUT = 0.2         # Helps slow down overfitting of data when recurrently training

##############################################################################################

# fix random seed for reproducibility
numpy.random.seed(SEED)


readData = pd.read_csv(URL, header=None, names=['label', 'message'], sep=SEPERATOR)

# convert label to a numerical variable
readData['label_num'] = readData.label.map({'Liberal' : 0, 'Neutral': 0.5, 'Conservative' : 1})
X = readData.message    # Contains the dataset's actual sentences that were labeled
Y = readData.label_num  # Either 0.0, 0.5, or 1.0 depending on label mapped to

# load the dataset into training and testing datasets
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, random_state=RANDOM_STATE)

# truncate and pad input sequences
for sentence in X_train:
    sentence.zfill(MAX_REVIEW_LENGTH)
for sentence in X_test:
    sentence.zfill(MAX_REVIEW_LENGTH)

# create the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(TOP_WORDS, EMBEDDING_VECTOR_LENGTH, input_length=MAX_REVIEW_LENGTH))
model.add(LSTM(100, recurrent_dropout=RECURRENT_DROPOUT dropout=DROPOUT))    # Dropouts help prevent overfitting

model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))                   # Layers deal with a 2D tensor, and output a 2D tensor
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), epochs=NUMBER_OF_EPOCHS, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)

# Final evaluation of the model
scores = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=0)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))
```

It is training a .tsv file that has data like this:

```
"Liberal","Forcing middle-class workers to bear a greater share of the cost of government weakens their support for needed investments and stirs resentment toward those who depend on public services the most ."

"Liberal", "Because it would not be worthwhile to bring a case for $ 30.22 , the arbitration clause would , as a practical matter , deny the Concepcions any relief and , more important , eliminate a class action that might punish AT&T for its pattern of fraudulent behavior ."
```

I try to run it and I get this from the console and I have no idea how to fix it nor do my professors trying to help me with this research:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
embedding_1 (Embedding)      (None, 500, 32)           160000
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 100)               53200
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 202
=================================================================
Total params: 213,402
Trainable params: 213,402
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LSTM-RNN.py", line 55, in <module>
    model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), epochs=NUMBER_OF_EPOCHS
, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
  File "C:\Users\Hydur\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\keras\models.py", line 871, in f
it
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "C:\Users\Hydur\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\keras\engine\training.py", line
1525, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "C:\Users\Hydur\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\keras\engine\training.py", line
1379, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')
  File "C:\Users\Hydur\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\keras\engine\training.py", line
144, in _standardize_input_data
    str(array.shape))
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected embedding_1_input to have shape (None, 50
0) but got array with shape (3244, 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main problem seems to be that X contained raw strings, while the Embedding layer expected data already coded numerically. The Keras [text preprocessing](https://keras.io/preprocessing/text/) utilities will take care of that:

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=MAX_REVIEW_LENGTH)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(readData.message)
X = numpy.array(tokenizer.texts_to_matrix(readData.message)) # shape (None, 500)

This will code each message as a 500 integers, with a unique integer assigned to each word.
```

Once that was fixed, I also got an error on the "dense_1" layer. The last layer in your network was specified to have two output nodes, but the loss function you used (binary_cross_entropy) expects a single column coded as 0/1. I edited it so that layer had only one output node so the process would complete, but doubt using 0, 0.5, 1 with binary cross entropy will do what you want. I think you'd probably be between off with a 3-level one-hot encoding and categorical_cross_entropy, but that's out of scope for this question.

Here is the full edited script that ran for me. I was only able to run it on the two observations you provided but it did complete.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import os, pickle, numpy, pandas as pd
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

################################### CONSTANTS ################################################
SEED = 7                        # Fixes random seed for reproducibility.
URL = 'ibcData.tsv'             # Specified dataset to gather data from.
SEPERATOR = '\t'                # Seperator the dataset uses to divide data.
RANDOM_STATE = 1                # Pseudo-random number generator state used for random sampling.
TOP_WORDS = 5000                # Most used words in the dataset.
MAX_REVIEW_LENGTH = 500         # Length of each sentence being sent in (necessary).
EMBEDDING_VECTOR_LENGTH = 32    # The specific Embedded later will have 32-length vectors to
                                # represent each word.
BATCH_SIZE = 64                 # Takes 64 sentences at a time and continually retrains RNN.
NUMBER_OF_EPOCHS = 3            # Fits RNN to more accurately guess the data's political bias.

# fix random seed for reproducibility
numpy.random.seed(SEED)


readData = pd.read_csv(URL, header=None, names=['label', 'message'], sep=SEPERATOR)

# convert label to a numerical variable
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=MAX_REVIEW_LENGTH)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(readData.message)
X = numpy.array(tokenizer.texts_to_matrix(readData.message)) # shape (None, 32)
readData['label_num'] = readData.label.map({'Liberal' : 0, 'Neutral': 0.5, 'Conservative' : 1})
Y = numpy.array(readData.label_num)  # Either 0.0, 0.5, or 1.0 depending on label mapped to


# load the dataset into training and testing datasets
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, random_state=RANDOM_STATE)

# create the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(TOP_WORDS, EMBEDDING_VECTOR_LENGTH, input_length=MAX_REVIEW_LENGTH))
model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))   # Layers deal with a 2D tensor, and output a 2D tensor
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), epochs=NUMBER_OF_EPOCHS, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)

# Final evaluation of the model
scores = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=0)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))
```

I then received the following output:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
embedding_1 (Embedding)      (None, 500, 32)           160000
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 100)               53200
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 101
=================================================================
Total params: 213,301
Trainable params: 213,301
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
Train on 1 samples, validate on 1 samples
Epoch 1/3
1/1 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6953 - acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.6814 - val_acc: 1.0000
Epoch 2/3
1/1 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6814 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.6670 - val_acc: 1.0000
Epoch 3/3
1/1 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6670 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.6516 - val_acc: 1.0000
```

Hope that helps.